# show/hide specific scripts from browsers (adblock)

Tags: firefox, browser, firefox-extensions, adblock

i'm using [AdBlock Plus](https://addons.mozilla.org/it/firefox/addon/adblock-plus/) and [Element Hiding Helper](https://addons.mozilla.org/it/firefox/addon/elemhidehelper/?src=ss) to show/hide dom element. 
 But i don't understand how can i show/hide a specific javascript script from page.

For example look this page:
http://downloadzoneforum.net

We have different **div, class: maintitle**. Every *div maintitle* have a spoiler. If click on **-** minus picture i can close the container.

[image: spoiler open]

Default *div maintitle* have spoilers opened. 
But i want hide *some* spoilers using a filter. When i open Firefox, i want see hidden this spoilers from **Extra Forum** and **Discussioni Varie**

Like this: 
[image: spoiler close]

**How Can i Do this using Adblock or Element Hiding Helper or Another Solution?**

Comment: You want them *closed* by default, not *hidden*. There's a difference. Adblock can hide, not close AFAIK.

Answer (score 2):

What you're trying to accomplish would be a lot easier with Greasemonkey. Greasemonkey allows you to customize the way a web page displays or behaves, by using small bits of JavaScript.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/